# SQL Server stored procedures contain SQL or call to view

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, view

Is it better practice to have references to views in your SQL Server stored procedures instead of the SQL code the view contains?

I see a lot of code like:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Report_65PlusLivingAlone]

As
Begin

---- Select all 3 groups from base table
Select 
    * 
INTO 
    #Temphouseholds
FROM
(
select  b.ReportYearDescription as CensusYear
        , Case When a.AggregationLevel = 'Minnesota' then 'Statewide'
               Else a.AggregationLevel
          End as AggregationLevel
        , a.PopulationType
        , a.PopulationSize
        , Case When a.PopulationType in 
                    ('Non-Family Households, Living Alone, Age 65 +'
                        ,'Living alone, age 65 and older') then 'households_livingalone'
                When a.PopulationType = 'Householders age 65 and older' then 'householders_65plus'
                Else 'total_households'
          End as PopulationGroups
        , Case  When b.ReportYearType = 'C'
                Then 'Current'
                Else 'Projected'
          End as censusgroups   
from    PublicReport_DSD.dbo.HouseholdCensusCountyInformation a
        , PublicReport_DSD.dbo.ReportYear b
where   a.PopulationType in ('Non-Family Households, Living Alone, Age 65 +'
                             ,'Living alone, age 65 and older'
                             ,'Householders age 65 and older'
                             ,'Total'
                            )
        and cast(a.CensusYear as varchar) = b.ReportYearDescription
        and b.ReportID = 18
        and b.IsActive = 1
) as Temphouseholds
```

that I want to rewrite so the SQL is in a view.
Does a view add overhead, or does, as I suspect, it give the server more information about what the sp is doing so it can optimize the sp better?

Thanks for the info,

-Beth

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Sql Server optimizer will probably (t-sql is usually a case of probably) treat both queries the same - the view won't offer anything extra to the compiler unless there is additional t-sql code, hints or SARGs.  Unless the view is indexed properly [it may indeed perform worse](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/tips/views_general_p1.aspx).

Comment: Good point about the article, although you shoul dread the comments especially, since the performance problems are not really backed with concrete examples. Also views do help you create better code. So unless your DB actually has performance issues, I would focus my efforts into solving business problems.

Comment: @gjvdkamp the comments on that article are interesting.  Nothing wrong with views - they can make sql code more readable and abstract away business logic (perform better than functions too in my experience), views can be more performant if they are indexed, but I think the OP is expecting a view will give the optimizer a hint (and therefore be faster) without any changes - which it won't.

Comment: I used a lot of views for a security layer and they were very complex. Ran perfectly after some tuning, don't think it could have been faster. And if you stick to the view, even for updates, you can ensure that you never breach security. Try that with handcoding all those joins into every procedure. So thinking about it I totally disagree with the author. I doubt there is a measurable perforance hit, and they let you create a layer that you can code against. So I think views, unless you really have a problem.

Comment: @gjvdkamp good point about security, also views enforce better DRY rules.

Comment: @Beth, we reached an agreement. Go with views!

Comment: @Beth but index them if you want better performance.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432.aspx

Comment: All the code reuse and abstractions in sql is not the same as in other languages and will kill performance if you start creating a view of a view of a view...